# How to add a new row below a selected row in Tabulator tables?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I would like to add new row below selected row in a tabulator table with an add button.
But every time new row is added at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling this in the `cellClick` event for a cell then the cell component will be passed into the function, you could get the row component from this and pass it into the `addRow` function:

```js
cellClick:function(e, cell){
    table.addRow({name:"Billy Bob", age:"12"}, false, cell.getRow()); //add new row below this row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this can help you (http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/update):

> If you want to add the row next to an existing row you can pass an optional third argument to the function that will position the new row next to the specified row (above or below based on the value of the second argument). This argument will take any of the standard row component look up options:

> ```
> table.addRow({name:"Billy Bob", age:"12"}, true, 3); //add new row above existing row with index of 3
> ```